# set width and height of an SVG element - d3.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg, d3.js

I am using d3 to build up a graph.

Now, i am trying to set width and height of that **area** ike this -

```
   var area2 = d3.svg.area()
            .interpolate("monotone")
            .attr("width", this.options.width)
            .attr("height", 100);
```

But, i get this error --

Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

See here - 
[image]

*NOTE: I have tested and `this.options.width` is not null - It's value is 1727.*

I am new to d3 and SVG, any suggestion will help.

Comment: Take a look at how SVG area operates. You don't provide a height and width. You provide x, y0 and y1. http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3883195

Answer (score 1, accepted):

svg.area provides x, y0, and y1 (as was previously stated by In Code). y0 to y1 is bottom to the top - bottom of graph (x axis) to the line if it is a line graph.

Something like this sounds like what you want:

```
  var area2 = d3.svg.area()
        .x(function(d) { return x(d.X_VARIABLE); })
        .y0(height)
        .y1(function(d) { return y(d.Y_VARIABLE); });
```

Great example: http://www.d3noob.org/2013/01/filling-area-under-graph.html

As noted by the author, you should be defining your domains for x and y as well (if you have not).

Comment: Fine, take my Karma :)